# Need to source java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 specifically and install?

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-8, x86-64, alternate

App throwing error at startup looking specifically for java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64. Environment is Ubuntu1604. Java java-8-openjdk-i386 is already installed , but need the amd64 and then use it as an alternate. Where can I source amd64 tar file ? Have ran "sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk". thx

2/6/21 current status - have not being able to install Java 8 AMD64.

Hi there, I tried :

```
sudo tar xvf jdk-8u291-linux-x64.tar.gz --directory /usr/lib/jvm/ 
and this installed to /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_291.
```

However I was expecting /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 folder structure.

Whats currently installed is:

```
ubuadmin@ubu1604OAEdd:/usr/lib/jvm$ ls -lrta
total 24
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root    23 Feb 25  2016 default-java -> java-1.8.0-openjdk-i386
drwxr-xr-x  8 10143 10143 4096 Apr  7 20:26 jdk1.8.0_291
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root  2716 Apr 21 17:10 .java-1.8.0-openjdk-i386.jinfo
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root    19 Apr 21 17:10 java-1.8.0-openjdk-i386 -> java-8-openjdk-i386
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  root  4096 Jun  1 23:17 java-8-openjdk-i386
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Jun  1 23:17 openjdk-8
drwxr-xr-x 69 root  root  4096 Jun  1 23:43 ..
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  root  4096 Jun  2 09:26 .

ubuadmin@ubu1604OAEdd:/usr/lib/jvm$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-8u292-b10-0ubuntu1~16.04.1-b10)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
ubuadmin@ubu1604OAEdd:/usr/lib/jvm$

ubuadmin@ubu1604OAEdd:/usr/lib/jvm$  sudo update-alternatives --config java
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
ubuadmin@ubu1604OAEdd:/usr/lib/jvm$
```

How can I complete the install. The app I'm trying to use is looking for :
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your question as-is - you can find links to all jdk implementations on [jdk.dev](https://jdk.dev) . But you'll have to extract jdk and add bin directory to PATH by yourself

As for updating alternatives it's a question for askubuntu.com, but I believe, that you should do install before updating.

```sh
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_291/bin/java" 1
```

Comment: Thanks, got some files. Wanted to try out : tar -xzf archive-name.tar.gz
cd archive-name      
./configure
make
sudo make install  . However when I extracted the tar file I dont have a 'configure' file to work with. Need that before running make. There are no  .sh files in the bin sub folder. Dont have 'autogen.sh' either. How can I install the OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64 files ? thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want to compile jdk from source? Because you can download already compiled jdk, unarchive it and then all bin directory to PATH. After that you can use javac command

Comment: Added comment above as I wasnt able to complete task  - any help appreciated. thx

Comment: I have updated my answer, maybe that would help